# OpenCV Java arithmetic actions on Mat

Tags: java, opencv, math

I need to convert code from c++ to Java. The problem arose when I started to convert code which alters Mat object data with arithmetic actions. How could I do these actions in Java:

```
MatOfFloat diff_im = <initialization>
MatOfFloat add_im =  <initialization>
int c = 200;
MatOfFloat o = diff_im/(add_im/2);
MatOfFloat uf = 128 + c*o;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with Java.  Unlike C++, there's no way for you to overload operators for your objects.  You do something like this to use a fluent style:

```
public class MathDouble {

    private double value;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        MathDouble x = new MathDouble(5);
        MathDouble y = new MathDouble(6);
        System.out(x.add(y));        
    }

    public MathDouble(double v) { this.value = v; }

    public MathDouble add(MathDouble c) {
        return new MathDouble(this.value + c.value); 
    }

    public String toString() { return Double.toString(this.value); }
}
```

I'd wonder what your `MatObject` class offers over and above the standard float and double types besides wrapping.  Seems like a lot of work for no value.

There are `Complex` and `Rational` number classes available in libraries that do provide special value, but neither one can overload operators.  You have to use a fluent style and write methods.

Just checked [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) using Google.  Are you asking how to extend their existing Java API?